# Обособление приложений, нужны ли запятые

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, приложения

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с обособлением приложений. Нужны ли в данных примерах запятые и почему?

1. Бронемашина с командиром роты капитаном Сергеем Алексеевым подъезжает к посту.
2. Начальник завода, старший инженер Валерий Кошкин, объясняет нам принцип работы механизма.
3. Его отец Иван Иванович прожил долгую и счастливую жизнь.

Answer (score 1):

Знаки расставлены верно:

1. *Бронемашина с **командиром роты капитаном** Сергеем Алексеевым подъезжает к посту.*
2. *Начальник завода, **старший инженер Валерий Кошкин**, объясняет нам принцип работы механизма.*
3. *Его отец **Иван Иванович** прожил долгую и счастливую жизнь.*

Это тема однородных, неоднородных и уточняющих приложений. Выбор нужно делать **по контексту, по смыслу**.

В предложении 1 приложения **неоднородные**: должность и звание, то есть дается полная информация о конкретном лице.

В предложении 2 **уточняющее** приложение  о должности начальника завода.

В предложении 3 **неоднородные** приложения, но это нужно уточнять по тексту: является ли информация об имени основной или уточняющей.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!